# Как добавить параметры в url?

Tags: запрос, angular

Подскажите, как добавить параметры в url для запроса к API в этот метод:

```
  public get(url: string = ''): Observable<any> {
    this.user = this.store.snapshot().user;

    console.log(this.user);
    const userId = this.user.userId;
    return this.httpClient.get(this.getUrl(url));
  }
```

Я хочу добавить userId в строку запроса, например: home/position?userId=133r4322r34

Comment: `const params = new HttpParams().set('userId', '133r4322r34'); return this.http.get(url, { params })`

Comment: Спасибо! работает